# How to get the last value of an element with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

how can i retrieve the last children of an element with XSLT
for example:

```
<zoo>
  <example>
     <name>A</name>
  </example>
  <example>
       <name>B</name>
  </example>
  <example>
        <name>C</name>
  </example>
  <example>
        <name>D</name>
  </example>
</zoo>
```

How can i retrieve **D**?
Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an expression like:

```
/*/example[last()]/name
```

Or:

```
/*/example[last()]/name/text()
```

The following stylesheet literally just outputs `D` (relying on the built-in template for text nodes):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/example[last()]/name"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```